# ¿Como hacer registros en la base de datos con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Este es el código que tengo hecho

```
       <?php
      $enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "loteriav2");
if (!$enlace) {
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
  $Nombre_loteria = $_POST['nombre'];
  mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO loterias ('Nombre_loteria') VALUES ($Nombre_loteria)");
  mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO datos_2dig ('N_loteria') VALUES ($Nombre_loteria)");
  mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO datos_2dig ('ultimo_ingreso_2dig') VALUES (0)");
  for ($i=1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO datos_2dig ('dig". $i ."') VALUES (0)";
    mysqli_query($enlace, $sql);
  }
  mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO datos_3dig ('N_loteria') VALUES ($Nombre_loteria)");
  mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO datos_3dig ('ultimo_ingreso_2dig') VALUES (0)");
  for ($i=1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO datos_2dig ('dig". $i ."') VALUES (0)";
    mysqli_query($enlace, $sql);
  }
  header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

La página simplemente no hace nada, no registra nada en la base de datos. Es como si no existiera, siquiera me arroja un mensaje de error o algo parecido.
Se que pueda parecer muy tonto pero tengo muy poca práctica, quisiera saber en que me estoy equivocando. 
     De antemano, muchas gracias aquien me pueda dar una mano con mi problema. para todo el que quiera aqui esta el codigo completo en GitHub https://github.com/Gianfranco97/LoteriaV2.git

Comment: Hola Gianfranco, bienvenido a SO español, coloca más información a la pregunta para poderte ayudar de mejor manera, por ejemplo coloca los  errores que lanza tu script de php para saber donde esta tu error.

Comment: simplemente no hace nada, no registra en absoluto, es como si el código no existiera.

Comment: Coloca lo que tienes en tu archivo conex.php, tal vez esta fallando la conexion a mysql desde php

Comment: listo, ya agregue esa parte del código

Comment: Al inicio de tu script coloca `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` para activar la visibilidad de errores, y luego ejecuta tu script, si sale algun error colocalo en la pregunta.

Comment: nada amigo, lo acabo de probar y sigue sin hacer nada, incluso quite el `header("Location: index.php");` para que se quedara ahí mismo, dando como resultado una pantalla en blanco y ningún dato almacenado.

Comment: Que entorno estas usando para php, LAMP o XAMPP??

Comment: estoy utilizando xampp

Comment: Abre la consola de XAMPP y revisa los logs de apache, mira si existen errores en el server.

Comment: como se hace eso?, por favor podrías ser un poco mas detallado en los pasos a seguir. de verdad nunca he hecho eso, hasta el momento nunca había tenido mayores problemas con mi código

Comment: Si usas xampp abre xampp control panel, al lado del boton de iniciar apache se encuentran los botones: admin, config y logs, da click en logs, luego se te despliega una lista de archivos de logs, da click Apache(error.log), se te abrirá un documento de texto con los errores que han ocurrido en el server, revisalos para ver que errores existen.

Comment: Te faltan comillas en los insert (si nombre es un varchar)

Comment: como así?... en que parte irían las comillas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probando el código de tu repositorio github, el error es lo que dice @AlvaroMontoro las comillas, actualmente tus querys estan asi:

```
  $Nombre_loteria = $_POST['nombre'];
  mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO loterias ('Nombre_loteria') VALUES ($Nombre_loteria)");
  mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO datos_2dig ('N_loteria') VALUES ($Nombre_loteria)");
  mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO datos_2dig ('ultimo_ingreso_2dig') VALUES (0)");
```

Deberian ir así:

```
  $Nombre_loteria = $_POST['nombre'];
  mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO loterias (Nombre_loteria) VALUES ('$Nombre_loteria')") or die("q1".mysqli_error($enlace));
  mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO datos_2dig (N_loteria) VALUES ('$Nombre_loteria')") or die("q2".mysqli_error($enlace));
  mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO datos_2dig (ultimo_ingreso_2dig) VALUES ('0')") or die("q3".mysqli_error($enlace));
  for ($i=1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO datos_2dig (dig". $i .") VALUES (0)";
    mysqli_query($enlace, $sql);
  }
  mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO datos_3dig (N_loteria) VALUES ('$Nombre_loteria')") or die("q4".mysqli_error($enlace));
  mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO datos_3dig (ultimo_ingreso_2dig) VALUES (0)") or die("q5".mysqli_error($enlace));
  for ($i=1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO datos_2dig (dig". $i .") VALUES (0)";
    mysqli_query($enlace, $sql) or die("q6".mysqli_error($enlace));
  }
```

Aunque aun así seguirá fallando ya que en tu base de datos la columna `ultimo_ingreso_2dig` esta declarada como not null, por lo que el insert del segundo query fallará, para corregir eso puedes insertar ese dato en el segundo query sin hacerlo por separado en el tercer query

```
mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO loterias (Nombre_loteria) VALUES ('$Nombre_loteria')") or die("q1".mysqli_error($enlace));
mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO datos_2dig (N_loteria, ultimo_ingreso_2dig) VALUES ('$Nombre_loteria',0)") or die("q2".mysqli_error($enlace));
```

en el segundo query ingresas las dos columnas en una sola llamada.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, de verdad ^_^